# Output row of Asterisks using a for-loop

Tags: java, for-loop

I have to make a row of as asterisks equal to the input of the user but it has to use the for statement.
For example if user inputs 5, 5 asterisks will be outputted in a row. For 5 it works - but not for other numbers.

This is what I have so far.

```
     Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
     for(int i =input.nextInt(); i<10;i++){
          System.out.print("*");
     }
```

Comment: if it's i < input.nextInt() it would read a new int with every iteration - which might not be wise...

Comment: Thanks guys why am I being nailed with -1s tho it was pretty clear

Comment: Probably because your description of your problem was "butit is wrong".

Comment: And because your question is *very* simple and can be catered to by going through a Java for-loop tutorial

Comment: @Drew Well I gave you a minus because I'm annoyed by the far too common "lol I'm so dumb, here's some code, plz help me ;)" way of posting questions. You don't need to specify that you're a "noob" in the title, it's quite clear from the question. It's also completely unnecessarily to apologize in questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is :-). You count from 0 *to* your value, right? So read your int *before* the loop and use the variable as the loop *end condition*:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
int num = input.nextInt();
for(int i =0; i<num; i++) {
      System.out.print("*");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code might help. The while loop continuously ask number input. When 0 is input, the loop stops and program terminates. For other no-zero values the loop continues to print asterisks.

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
int num;
while((num = input.nextInt()) != 0) {
   for(int i =0; i<num; i++) {
      System.out.print("*");
   }
}
```